# sql nested query - group results by parent

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

I have the need to return tree like results from a single table. At the moment im using connect by and start with to ensure that all the correct results are returned.

```
select id,parent_id
     from myTable 
 connect by prior id = parent_id start with name = 'manager' 
     group by id, parent_id
 order by parent_id asc
```

However i want the results to return in tree structure. So each time a parent row is found its children rows will be displayed directly underneath it. Then move onto next parent and do the same

Expected results

```
  - Parent A
   - child a
   - child b 
  - Parent B
   - child c
   - child d
```

Actual results

```
- Parent A 
- Parent B
- child a 
- child b 
- child c 
- child d
```

Is it possible to do this in oracle? My table uses a parent_id field to identify when a row has a parent. Every row also has a sort order, which is the order it should be sorted under its parent and a unique Id.

I'm using an Oracle DB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to use `ORDER SIBLINGS BY`. The query you have is ordering by the `parent_id` column which is overriding any hierarchical ordering.

The query below should do what you need it to do:

```
with my_hierarchy_data as (
  select 1 as id, null as parent_id, 'Manager' as name from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 1 as parent_id, 'parent 1' as name from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 1 as parent_id, 'parent 2' as name from dual union all
  select 4 as id, 2 as parent_id, 'child 1' as name from dual union all
  select 5 as id, 2 as parent_id, 'child 2' as name from dual union all
  select 6 as id, 3 as parent_id, 'child 3' as name from dual union all
  select 7 as id, 3 as parent_id, 'child 4' as name from dual 
)
select id, parent_id, lpad('- ', level * 2, ' ') || name as name
from my_hierarchy_data
connect by prior id = parent_id
start with name= 'Manager'
order siblings by parent_id asc
```

Comment: the tabbing is not a requirement so i can also remove the lpad and just use select id, parent_id, level, name. And it works as required.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a special value `level` that can be used in Oracle hierarchical queries.  It returns 1 for rows at the top level of the hierarchy, 2 for their children, and so on.  You can use this to create indentation like this:

```
select lpad('- ',level*2,' ') || name
     from myTable 
 connect by prior id = parent_id start with name = 'manager' 
     group by id, parent_id
```

Comment: thanks Tony, do i need to lpad each field i return in the select? I'm getting a 'not a group by expression'. Just some more context on this. Im passing the results back to a Java app which will expect the results already sorted so it can display. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed the GROUP BY.   I guess just change to "group by lpad('- ',level*2,' ') || name"?

Comment: the query doesn't however just displays the results in the exact same order just now with tabs depending on the level in the hierarchy

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "tabs"?  You need to get rid of the ORDER BY though to get the hierarchical ordering instead.

Comment: apologies, i should have been clearer in the description. thanks for useful feedback however